# Trigger custom button

Tags: custom-button, button

Is there a way to create `WF/Apex Trigger` to trigger a button on the record.

we use *Zuora for SalesForce quote* when customer accept the quote sales rep get an email notification through Sertifi e-signature (which is also configured in SalesForce), then the user goes into the quote to click `Send to Zuora` button which will change the status of the quote from `New` to `Sent to z-bill` and eventually Zuora will receive the quote.

We want to automate the process so that when customer accept the quote then quote should be sent from salesforce to Zuora. any help would be really appreciated.

PS - Sertifi status shows pending when the quote is sent to the customer and when customer accepts it, the status will changed to `Signed`.

Comment: From your post it looks like you want to change status from `Signed` to `Sent to z-bill`, it should be possible through workflow. Check what `Send to Zuora` button does apart from changing status, maybe its calling some API?

Comment: I think you can read this page which says you can create your own send to zuora process and/or bypass the details page using [sendToZBilling](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CA_Commerce/I_Development_Resources/C_Component_Library/G_Component_Library_Sample_Code/C_Creating_Your_Own_%22Send_to_Z-Billing%22_Process) method

Comment: @ Rahul - all i want is to send the quote from SF to Zuora without manually hitting "Send to Zuora" button. I created WF to change the value in the status field which worked fine but quote is not getting sent to Zuora. i think it is calling API  but Iam not a developer to understand the logic.

Comment: @Manjit - Our developer has done that bit, now the question is how to hit "SendToZBilling" button automatically based on certain field update in the system.

Comment: DML does not execute buttons. DML can (through code/process builder) invoke http callouts

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

Zuora managed package provides the ability to invoke the send to z-Billing programmatically, check [this](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CA_Commerce/I_Development_Resources/C_Component_Library/C_Global_Classes/F_sendToZBilling_Method), you have to call this method and provide your quoteId. There are different ways to achieve the functionality, if I were to design I would do this,

1. Introduce a new status on Quote, let say 'Sending to Zuora'. Using
   the same workflow rule that you already built, update the quote
   status to 'Sending to Zuora' whenever the quote is e-Signed
2. Implement a new apex class to call the above mentioned managed
   package method with your quote Id. Note - There is some sample code in the article down below
3. Write a trigger on Quote that will call the apex class, the
   condition is whenever the status is 'Sending to Zuora'.
4. The manage package method automatically updates the status to 'Sent to z-Billing' if the call is successful, otherwise the status will remain the same and the error gets updated on the quote
5. Build a new view to display the quote with status 'Sending to Zuora' or run a schedule job nightly (or whatever interval) to email the sales reps about the failed quotes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: There is no `Set allow callouts - True` on a trigger. do you mean to have the trigger call a future method with those settings?

Comment: That's correct, future method with Callout = True